# Launch Image Splash Screen Animation in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, splash-screen

I want to create a twitter like launch image for my ios app in swift.

I do understand the general problem with animated launch images, and I basically know the steps to create such an animation:

1. Add a new view, right after the app launched, with the exact same content as the launchimage
2. Animate that view
3. Let the view disappear

I found this brilliant source: http://iosdevtips.co/post/88481653818/twitter-ios-app-bird-zoom-animation

But this guy uses a mask and I am not able to change his code to get the "real" twitter like animation without a mask, but just an animated (zoom in) image.

So how do I add a new view to the current view? If I use a subview, how do I identify that view later on the progress when I need to delete the subview in animationDidStop?

Oh and I'd love to do all that in the AppDelegate.

Here is my current approach:

Setting up the view in AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var viewForLayer: UIView!
    var window: UIWindow?

    var emoji: CALayer {
      return viewForLayer.layer
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

      self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
      // step 1: recreate the launch image

      self.emoji.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 52/255, green: 52/255, blue: 52/255, alpha: 0).CGColor
      self.emoji.contents = UIImage(named: "SplashScreenEmoji")!.CGImage

      self.emoji.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
      self.emoji.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
      self.emoji.position = CGPoint(x: self.window!.frame.size.width/2, y: self.window!.frame.size.height/2)

      // self.window!.addSubview(viewForLayer) or
      viewForLayer.layer.addSublayer(emoji)

      // step 2: add the animation to that view
      animateEmoji()

      self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
      return true
    }
}
```

For the animation:

```
func animateEmoji() {
    let keyFrameAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    keyFrameAnimation.delegate = self
    keyFrameAnimation.duration = 1
    keyFrameAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1 //add delay of 1 second
    let initalBounds = NSValue(CGRect: emoji.bounds)
    let secondBounds = NSValue(CGRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90))
    let finalBounds = NSValue(CGRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1500, height: 1500))
    keyFrameAnimation.values = [initalBounds, secondBounds, finalBounds]
    keyFrameAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.3, 1]
    keyFrameAnimation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut), CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)]
    self.emoji.addAnimation(keyFrameAnimation, forKey: "bounds")
}

override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    // step 3: remove the view
    self.viewForLayer.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I always get an fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, i guess this is because of the

```
var emoji: CALayer {
   return viewForLayer.layer
}
```

I definitely stuck and need the help of the stackoverflow community, please don't judge since I am new here and just learn how to code swift ;)

Thanks,
jo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use layers, you can achieve your zoom effect simply via `UIView`s and `UIView` animation blocks.

Create a custom view controller with just an image view added to its view, assign that view controller as a window's `rootViewController`. Use a `UIView` animation block to increase the scale of the image view (via `CGAffineTransform`). In the animation's completion block, you can assign your actual initial view controller to the window's `rootViewController`.

Comment: Great! That works for me. I only got one problem left. Once the animation is over, this code should show my initial rootview controller:

override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
        
        self.window!.rootViewController = Nav1()
}

but for some reason i can only see the nav1 viewController with a very dark shadow on it and without any content.

Comment: rounak? Or does anyone else know how to fix this?

Comment: @JoF.T. have you correctly assigned the delegate for the animation?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? The animation happens within the AppDelegate. I'm creating an UINavigationController called "splashScreen"  for the animation within the AppDelegate. The animation also happens in the AppDelegate. Do you mean something like splashScreen.delegate = self ?

Comment: Basically if you put a break point in animationDidStop, does Xcode break over there?

Comment: xcode runs the animationDidStop function properly, @rounak

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to replicate your error here but I can spot the source.

When you write

```
var emoji: CALayer {
    return viewForLayer.layer
}
```

and subsequently call on this variable with *self.emoji*, or

```
viewForLayer.layer.addSublayer(emoji)
```

you are actually implicitly unwrapping the variable *viewForLayer*, which has a type of an implicitly unwrapped optional *UIView*:

```
var viewForLayer: UIView!
```

The only explanation in my mind is that for some reason *viewForLayer* is nil when you call it, which will precisely cause an error when implicitly unwrapped (i.e. used in any way). I don't know your code well but I can't see where you have initialised *viewForLayer*, by which I mean give it a non-nil value.

Comment: Thanks Richard. So I am working with the xcode storyboard. My idea was it to programmatically create an new empty UIView where I can add the Animation. Does this View has to exist on my rootviewcontroller within the storyboard? I've tried that too, but i wasn't able to link the view to the appDelegate file (by linking i mean creating an IBOutlet). 

i adjusted this line to initialize the view in my appdelegate: 
var viewForLayer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0 , 0, 100, 100))